# Regex for brainfuck loops

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, brainfuck

I'd like to create a *regular expression* that is able to fetch every loop inside a brainfuck code.

Let's say this code is given:

```
++++[>+[>,++.]<<-]++[>,.<-]
```

I want to fetch these three loops (actually it would be sufficient just to fetch the first one):

```
[>+[>,++.]<<-]
[>,++.]
[,.<-]
```

My knowledge of regular expressions is pretty weak, so I can't do much more than *basics*. What I have thought of is this expression:

```
\[[-+><.,\[\]]*]

\[            - Match the first (opening) bracket
[-+><.,\[\]]* - followed by a number of brainfuck operators
]             - followed by a closing bracket
```

This however matches (*obviously*) everything between the first opening, and the last closing bracket:

```
[>+[>,++.]<<-]++[>,.<-]
```

It might need something to test for the same number of opening and closing brackets inside the loop, before matching the last closing bracket - If that makes any sense.

Maybe a lookaround (I need to use this in javascript, so I can only use **lookaheads**) is the right way to do this, but I can't figure out how it's supposed to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had written this one once when I needed to match a pair of square brackets (while handling nesting correctly)

It is a .NET regex that uses some features that aren't available in all regex engines. Here goes:

```
\[(?>\[(?<d>)|\](?<-d>)|.?)*(?(d)(?!))\]
```

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions cannot match infinitely recursing things. Look at the Chomsky hierarchy of languages.

You can write a regular expression matching finitely recursing things by expanding them. For example, this POSIX ERE (tested with egrep) will match brainfuck loops up to nesting depth 3:

```
(\[[^][]*\]|\[([^][]|\[[^][]*\])*|\[([^][]|\[([^][]|\[[^][]*\])*\])*\])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a non-greedy (or lazy) matching:

```
\[[-+><.,\[\]]*?\]
```

Notice the `?`. Though, it'll match the shortest string between `[` and `]`. Thus, one of the results would be:

```
[>+[>,++.]
```

Comment: This matches `[>+[>,++.]` and `[>,.<-]`. I need to match the whole first loop (including `<<-]`, like this: `[>+[>,++.]<<-]`)